# mvc 5 validate date in the past

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I saw the questions here but I was not able to solve the problem.

I want when a user inserts date in the form only date in the past will be relevant.

Example:

The user can't insert date after 02/03/2016.

**My model:**

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
[Display(Name = "Date")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is mandatory")]
public DateTime created_date { get; set; }
```

**My view:**

```
<div class="form-group" >
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.created_date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10" >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.created_date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.created_date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: Since you appear to be wanting the HTML5 browser datepicker (which is only supported in Chrome and Edge), the format must be `DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}"` in order to work correctly. You should consider using a custom validation attribute to get both client and server side validation.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `HTML 5` date type, as an example:

```
<input type="date" max="2016-03-02">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nsvno84t/1/

To do this with Razor which will give you todays date:

```
<input type="date" max='@DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")'>
```

However you may want to determine the users/servers date time settings as this would work for a UK format (Something like `@DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` may be better in your case).

You should also validate it against the server as well as the client, in your MVC code you could use the `ValidationAttribute`.

```
public class RestrictedDate : ValidationAttribute
{
   public override bool IsValid(object date) 
   {
       DateTime date = (DateTime)date;
       return date < DateTime.Now;
   }
}
```

Then use the new `RestrictedDate` attribute on your model:

```
public class YourModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is mandatory")]
    [RestrictedDate]
    public DateTime created_date { get; set; } 
}
```

As an additional note, you may also want to consider changing `created_date` to `CreatedDate` to conform to `C#` naming conventions.

Comment: I write this class in the model? or in the model folder? and I have error in this line DateTime date = (DateTime)date;

Comment: why i cant mention @Darren Davies?

Comment: can you help me @Darren Davies?

Comment: @MaorAzulay - I would write the RestrictedDate class in a Validation or Attributes folder and then reference the new class within your model.  What is the error you receive? An InvalidCast exception? If so try DateTime.TryParse, if you have other errors please post a new question and I'll try and help :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest validating in the controller using conditional statements.  I don't know if you are in your `Create` or `Edit` view, but in your controller you could validate like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID, created_date" /* and whatever else you have in your model*/)] YourModel yourModel)

if(ModelState.IsValid)
{
    if (yourModel.created_date > DateTime.Today)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("created_date", "Date cannot be set to future date!");
        return View(yourModel);
    }

    return View(yourModel);
}
```

But that is validating against the server.. so I would also suggest combining that validation with client side validation which @Darren Davies gave in his answer..

Answer (score 0):

first you have to change

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

to 
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

beacuse some browser not give perfect result

Comment: you can explain to me? i use jquery